# Обращение к ячейке таблицы. Селекторы по атрибутам colspan и rowspan

Tags: html, css, таблицы

Все привет. Интересует такой вопрос, он наверное более академический:)Можно ли обратится к группе ячеек з разными атрибутами colspan, без добавление класса или других атрибутов. Например, у меня есть несколько ячеек с разными значением colspan, как к ним одновременно обратиться? Потому-что вот так как ниже, как-то некрасиво получается.

```
td[colspan = "3"], 
td[colspan = "4"], 
td[colspan = "5"] 
{ color: red;}
```

Я пробовал игратся с $ и * но не получается, может для css есть какое-то регулярное выражение для любых цифр?

Comment: так работает же, или вам не нравится перечисление через запятую?

Comment: ну а какая у вас тогда закономерность?? если написать `td[colspan]`- то затянет все `td` у которых есть `colspan`... такой сойдет??? ну или уточните вопрос

Comment: td[colspan] точно, об этом я не подумал. Да, такой вариант подходит. Спасибо!

Comment: Через запятую тоже работет, но если много колспан то как-то хочется чтобы все проще было. Плюс, ведь не всегда известно сколько этих колспанов будет в таблице а нужно чтобы их стилистика была одинаковой.